# Help Center > Reputation & Privileges Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, help-center

On the [Reputation & Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-reputation) Help page, the section about losing reputation is incorrect.

```
You lose reputation when: :

1. question is voted down: −2 (-1 to voter)
2. you place a bounty on a question: −full bounty amount
3. one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags:−100
```

First, there is a double `:` after "You lose reputation when".

Second, when a question is voted down, the question asker loses 2 points, but the voter **does not** lose any points. Voters only lose a point when downvoting an answer, while the person who posted the answer loses 2 points.

All-in-all, I believe this Help page could be more helpful, however I did not see a way for the community to suggest edits. This [answer on another meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/154928) seems very detailed and should be considered a replacement to the content of this help page.

Comment: It's nice to see that people are actually reading the thing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fixed now. Thanks for noticing.

You can suggest edits by emailing the [community team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other).

Comment: How about #3? See below.

Comment: I think it should be clarified that when downvoting an answer, you also lose 1 reputation point.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Done.